# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

In VB.NET i have Button1 which fills datagridview1 and what i want is to filter using textbox1_TextChanged as a filter of a specific column.

What am i doing Wrong ?
How can i create the new dvs with source from the already binded datasource of the grid ?

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim _Session As ESSession
        'Dim _dataset As DataSet
        Dim _IMainUI As IMainUI

        _IMainUI = Entersoft.Framework.Windows.Components.ESMainUI.GetMainUI()
        _Session = _IMainUI.UISession

        'Fill datagridview1
        Dim SQL As String = "SELECT  userid  ,name  , Inactive FROM esgouser order by userid"
        Dim SQLParams As Hashtable = ESResMngr.CreateCIHashTable()
        Dim ds As DataSet = _Session.FetchDS(SQL, Nothing, Nothing, SQLParams)
        Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
        Dim dv As New DataView(dt)


        'Dim k As New DataView(dt)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
        DataGridView1.Columns("Userid").DataPropertyName = "Userid"
        DataGridView1.Columns("Name").DataPropertyName = "Name"
        DataGridView1.Columns("InActive").DataPropertyName = "Inactive"
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows

            If row.Cells(2).Value = "0" Then

                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 250, 154)
            Else

                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 69, 0)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

        Dim dvs As New DataView(CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable))
        dvs.RowFilter = String.Format("userid like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = dvs

    End Sub
```

Comment: And one other question ... do you suggest using any other free third party datagridview control with active filtering on the top of everycolumn ?

Comment: `DataGridView1.DataSource = dt` (`dt`, not `dv`). After that, `DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = " ... "`. Remove the rest.

Comment: There's definitely no point creating and binding a `DataView` because, when you bind a `DataTable`, the data you see comes from its `DefaultView` anyway, and that's a `DataView`. That said, don't bind the `DataTable` to the grid either. Add a `BindingSource` in the designer, bind the `DataTable` to that and bind the `BindingSource` to the grid. You then filter and sort using the `Filter` and `Sort` properties of the `BindingSource`.

Comment: Also, there's no way that you should be setting the `DataPropertyName` of grid columns after binding. If those columns are generated automatically when you bind then the `DataPropertyName` is already set. If you're creating those columns in the designer then you should be setting the `DataPropertyName` in the designer. If you're creating the columns manually in code then you should be setting the `DataPropertyName` immediately in code. No matter how the columns are created, setting the `DataPropertyName` after binding is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you assign a `DataView` as source for the `DataGridView` in the following line :

```
Dim dv As New DataView(dt)
DataGridView1.DataSource = dv
```

and then you want to cast it to a `DataTable`:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim dvs As New DataView(CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable))
    ' ... 
End Sub
```

that doesn't work, you need to cast it to `DataView`:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim dvs As DataView = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataView)
    dvs.RowFilter = String.Format("userid like '%{0}%'", TextBox1.Text)
    ' DataGridView1.DataSource = dvs ' unnecessary
End Sub
```

Since it is already assigned to the `DataGridView1.DataSource` you can omit the last line.

Comment: Tim , this is also a correct answer ! Thank you very much ...